# Two equal items in alternatives list

Tags: jdk, update-alternatives

I want to have two JDKs. The first one was installed a long time ago to /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/. I installed the second version and executed following commands to add it to alternatives:

```
red-planet@laptop:~$ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/opt/java_1.6.0_35/bin/java" 2
update-alternatives: using /opt/java_1.6.0_35/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in auto mode.
red-planet@laptop:~$ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/opt/java_1.6.0_35/bin/javac" 2
update-alternatives: using /opt/java_1.6.0_35/bin/javac to provide /usr/bin/javac (javac) in auto mode.
red-planet@laptop:~$ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/opt/java_1.6.0_35/bin/javaws" 2
update-alternatives: using /opt/java_1.6.0_35/bin/javaws to provide /usr/bin/javaws (javaws) in auto mode.
```

And configured:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                 Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /opt/java_1.6.0_35/bin/java           2         auto mode
  1            /opt/java_1.6.0_35/bin/java           2         manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java   1         manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Why do I have two equal items in the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selection marked as 0 is not a duplicate, it just indicates what is currently the alternative with the highest priority, and therefore the one that will be used in auto mode.
In Auto mode whenever you add a new alternative the system always uses the one with the highest priority. In manual, the system honors your choice even if a higher priority alternative is available.
You can choose auto mode by selecting 0 at that prompt, or manual by entering the number corresponding to any of the alternatives. Look at the man page for more details

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you executed the install java command twice